# Jasmine doesn't exit on tests finishing causing CI to stall

Tags: node.js, terminal

I've written the following test command in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node spec",
},
```

When I run `npm test` all of my tests complete successfully, but the terminal process doesn't release control back to input, therefore when I deploy my application to CI it hangs on the build step due to it never appearing to finish.

I tried to do: `./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node spec && exit` but the `&& exit` command doesn't seem to relinquish control on complete either.

Comment: btw: You can write `"jasmine-node test"`instead of `"./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node spec"`

Comment: Do You have async tests?

Comment: I haven't set `jasmine` or `jasmine-node` up yet in my environment vars, so have to find the jasmine executable manually in the node modules directory - thanks though! :)

Comment: Yes, all of my tests are async as I'm testing HTTP responses from my internal API - I use `done()` to handle the async callbacks

Comment: NodeJS add `./node_modules/.bin/` to `PATH` in `scripts` section

Comment: Ok, I've done that - although I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by adding an `--forceexit` flag onto jasmine once it had finished running tests.

For those who stumble on this same issue in future:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine-node spec --forceexit"
},
```

Comment: PATH is unnecessary. Read https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#environment

Comment: Not working for me, am using jasmine-node@2.0.0 and jasmine@2.0.0